# The getter 'typeArguments' isn't defined for the class 'Annotation'

Tags: flutter, dart

I updated my flutter today and build_runner is not working getting this(below) error
Error- when i run flutter pun run build_runner build
tried every command

flutter clean |
flutter pub packages upgrade |
flutter pub cache repair
etc but not working

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      ...
      ...
      flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
      xml: ^4.2.0
      build_resolvers: ^1.5.4
      build: ^1.6.3
      injectable_generator: ^1.2.0
      convert: ^3.0.0
      glob: ^2.0.0
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      built_value_generator: ^7.0.9
      json_serializable: ^4.0.2
      build_runner: ^1.11.5
      retrofit_generator: ^1.3.7+2
      mobx_codegen: ^1.1.0+1
    
    dependency_overrides:
      convert: ^3.0.0
      pedantic: ^1.9.0
      analyzer: ^0.41.2



Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
../../flutter-dart/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_style-1.3.14/lib/src/source_visitor.dart:302:16: Error: The getter 'typeArguments' isn't defined for the class 'Annota
tion'.
 - 'Annotation' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../flutter-dart/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.41.2/lib/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'typeArguments'.
    visit(node.typeArguments);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It might be your dependency "analyzer" that is not compatible for the moment with flutter 2.0

Answer (score 5):

The issue is the dart_style package being an updated version that uses the latest analyzer package.

Downgrade the dart_style version under dependency_overrides:

```
dependency_overrides:
  dart_style: '>=1.3.13 <=1.3.13'
```

I have the same exact issue with the current version of mobx_codegen (1.1.2) + analyzer (0.41.1) and doing this worked.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to pinning `dart-style` you can also pin the Analyzer package to 0:41.1 which also seems to work and might not have any side effects of pinning style.

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 0.41.1
```